# Matching numbers inside nested numbered groups

Tags: regex

I am trying to find and capture all numbers inside ( and ) separately in my data, ignoring the rest of the numbers.

My data looks like this

```
21 [42] (12) 19 25 [44] (25 26 27) 17 (14 3) 8 1 6 (19)
```

So I want to find matches for `12`, `25`, `26`, `27`, `14`, `3` and `19`

I tried doing `\((\d+)\)*` but this only gives me `12`, `25`, `14`, `19`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine a positive lookahead with a negative lookahead to get your desired results.

```
(\d+)(?=(?:.(?!\())*\))
```

Regular expression:

```
(           group and capture to \1:
 \d+        digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
)           end of \1
(?=         look ahead to see if there is:
 (?:        group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
   .        any character except \n
   (?!      look ahead to see if there is not:
    \(      '('
   )        end of look-ahead
)*          end of grouping
 \)         ')'
)           end of look-ahead
```

See a [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/gM8yB9)

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `\d+(?=(((?!\().)*)\))` example [here](http://regexr.com?36as0)

modified to the following `(\d+)(?=(?:(?!\().)*\))` [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aJ8lA2)

Comment: This does not match what you expect

Comment: @hwnd: care to explain !! it seems fine to me from the example

Comment: Yes, see my [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/gM8yB9) and look at your [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aW2iB9)

Comment: ok, modified my example to include matching/non-matching groups, however you would want to write the negative lookahead before the match (the dot in this case), see my [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aJ8lA2) and look at your [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/nQ6dM8)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any nesting there.  Nesting implies something like this:

```
12 (34 (56) 78) 90
```

If you really have data like that--especially if you don't know how deep the nesting can go--I would advise you not to use regexes.  But your problem looks very simple; this should be all you need:

```
\d+(?=[^()]*\))
```

As with the other answers, the lookahead asserts that there's closing bracket up ahead, with no opening brackets between here and there.  I excluded closing brackets too, mostly for the sake of efficiency.  Otherwise it would tend to zoom on past the `)` at first, only to have to backtrack to it.